# Multiple Shipping Quotes After Upgrading Ubercart?

Tags: 6, ubercart

I have been using D6/UC2 on a big web store for a few years now. I upgraded with DRUSH a few months ago to 2.1, and with products added since then, uc_quote offers an additional First Class option that is too cheap, which is costing the client money. I have uc_quote echoing the request data for administrators, and it looks like there are two requests being sent to USPS quote API. Is it normal for two requests to be made?

Why would the cheap option would start appearing after an upgrade?

Comment: A clue? I have two items that are both saved with package quantity = 10. Before the upgrade, they would quote as one package with the combined weight. Now, they quote as two separate packages with correct weight for each. They need to go as one. USPS default, domestic and international all have "Quote Settings" marked as "All in one". I resaved the settings as "Each in its own package" and back to "Allin one" to make sure. Why the multiple quotes?

Comment: I found mention of this issue here: http://www.ubercart.org/project_issue/usps_shipping_ubercart_creates_multiple_packages_quote_only_shows_pricing_1_2_packages#comment-69996